# Items jump around chaotically

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

When I move the scroll bar a small amount, the cells jump around. It's not smooth scrolling at all. Is this an error with the code or is it tremendously bad performance? It does it when I remove the cell measurer too.

```
isRowLoaded = ({ index }) => {

        return index < this.props.shifts.length;
    }

    loadMoreRows = ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) => {

        var p = this.loadShiftsFromServer(startIndex, stopIndex);

        return p;
    }

    rowRenderer = ({ key, index, parent, style }) => {

        if (!this.isRowLoaded({ index })) {

            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        var s = this.props.shifts[index];

        return <CellMeasurer
            cache={this._cache}
            key={key}
            rowIndex={index}
            columnIndex={0}
            parent={parent}>
            {({ measure }) => (

                <Shift
                    key={s.sid}
                    shiftId={s.sid}

                />
            )}
        </CellMeasurer>;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={this.props.className + ' list'}>

                <InfiniteLoader 
                    isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
                    loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows}
                    rowCount={this.props.shifts.length + 1}
                >
                    {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (

                        <AutoSizer>
                            {({ width, height }) => (
                                <List
                                    width={width}
                                    height={height}
                                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                    ref={registerChild}
                                    rowCount={this.props.shifts.length + 1}
                                    rowHeight={20}
                                    rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                                />
                            )}
                                </AutoSizer>
                    )}
                </InfiniteLoader>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a repro? It's kind of hard to diagnose or comment on performance issues with only an unrunnable code sample.

Comment: That being said, you don't seem to be using the `style` property at all in your above example. This means you either shared the wrong code sample, or aren't using the library correctly.

Comment: @brianvaughn I'm not sure how to do that. Is there an existing repro or online Javascript runner that demonstrates infinite scroll using InfiniteLoader? Also, why is the `style` property necessary?

Comment: Read the docs w.r.t. the `style` property. It's key to windowing. Also check out this slide for a little background information: https://bvaughn.github.io/forward-js-2017/#/12/1

Comment: You can use CodeSandbox, CodePen, JSFiddle, etc. for creating online repros.

Comment: @bvaughn I've pretty much got this working except that when the "loading" row is visible, the API request pauses in "Pending" state on Chrome. It's a similar situation with Safari. After a couple of seconds or so, "Pending" ends but the time for the query is specified in milliseconds. If I scroll slowly such that the loading row isn't visible, it loads and populates rows smoothly and without delay.

Comment: You still haven't shared a repro.

Comment: @bvaughn Repro here... https://codesandbox.io/s/92jwo2x0p4. It seems to work ok. On my webpage however, I can scroll to the bottom such that the "loading" row is in view and keep scrolling down, with small pauses in between each gesture, and the network request stays perpetually in "Pending". If I stop scrolling, then after a couple of seconds, the network request completes. The debugger says that Javascript is idle for the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, if the repro case works fine. There is one small problem with your repro that should be fixed- the ids/keys are not unique since the test endpoint you're using returns the same 10 users each time. You could append the list-length to the string id each time to make them unique.

Comment: @bvaughn Yes, I noticed that. This is a strange problem. I've been able to mitigate it by setting a large page size of 200 and a threshold of 150. It's difficult to get to the bottom of the list now.